# subscriber information in zmq

Tags: c, publish-subscribe, zeromq

I have a simple ZMQ 3.2 publisher which sends out messages and there are N number of subscribers that connect and disconnect to this publisher.

Is there any way in which the publisher can have details(IP, Name, Type... etc) of the subscriber that connects to it?

Comment: I think you will have to incorporate this into your topology (i.e. send this information yourself)

Comment: What if I have my IP and port open to all so that any number of subscribers from anywhere can connect to it?

Hence I have no control over the subscribers and their details. Then how am I supposed to get them?